# Error fitting Tensorflow model only when the batch_size is specified

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm learning Tensorflow for machine learning and for one of my exercises I'm trying to fit a model using the functional API in such a way to have the model being a function of two variables of different types.

I was getting errors when running model.fit(), and found that removing the specification of the batch_size for one of the inputs makes the program run normally. I would like to understand why this is so.

I will show the relevant parts of my code and plots of my models for clarity. I am running everything in Google Colab. **The problem happens with the line x2_input = keras.Input(...) in the model definition**:

My last step in creating my dataset is:

```
data_train = tf.data.Dataset.zip((x_train,y_train))
data_train = data_train.batch(128).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

data_test = tf.data.Dataset.zip((x_test,y_test))
data_test = data_test.batch(128).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

and if I run

```
data_train,data_test
```

I get

```
(<PrefetchDataset shapes: (((None, 1), (None, 2)), (None, 5)), types: ((tf.string, tf.int64), tf.uint8)>,
 <PrefetchDataset shapes: (((None, 1), (None, 2)), (None, 5)), types: ((tf.string, tf.int64), tf.uint8)>)
```

Then, my model is defined as follows

```
tf.random.set_seed(33)
x1_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,),batch_size=128,dtype=tf.string,name="x1_input")
x1 = vectorizer(x1_input)
x1 = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vectorizer.vocabulary_size(),output_dim=64,name="x1_emb")(x1)
x1 = layers.Conv1D(64,2,padding="same",activation="relu",name="x1_conv")(x1)
x1 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="x1_pool")(x1)
x1 = layers.Dense(len(df.target.unique()),activation="softmax",name="x1_dense")(x1)
modelx1 = tf.keras.Model(x1_input,x1)

x2_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2,),dtype=tf.int64,name="x2_input")
x2 = layers.Dense(64,activation="sigmoid",name="x2_dense1")(x2_input)
x2 = layers.Dense(len(df.target.unique()),activation="softmax",name="x2_dense2")(x2)
modelx2 = tf.keras.Model(x2_input,x2)

x = layers.Concatenate()([modelx1.output,modelx2.output])
output = layers.Dense(len(df.target.unique()),activation="softmax")(x)

model0 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[modelx1.input,modelx2.input],outputs=output)
model0.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
               optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
               metrics=["accuracy"])

model0.fit(data_train,epochs=5,
           validation_data=data_test)
```

Here is a plot of my model:
[link to the plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtZKL.png)

**This runs fine, but if I add batch_size=128 to the arguments of x2_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2,),dtype=tf.int64,name="x2_input"), I get the following error after the first epoch:**

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-202-176df26aa2ef> in <module>()
     22 
     23 model0.fit(data_train,epochs=5,
---> 24            validation_data=data_test)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     58     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 59                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     60   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     61     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 4672 values, but the requested shape has 8192
     [[node gradient_tape/model_230/x1_pool/Reshape
 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:464)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_85580]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node gradient_tape/model_230/x1_pool/Reshape:
In[0] model_230/x1_pool/Max (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py:2415)   
In[1] gradient_tape/model_230/x1_pool/DynamicStitch:

Operation defined at: (most recent call last)
>>>   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>>>     "__main__", mod_spec)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>>>     exec(code, run_globals)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
>>>     app.launch_new_instance()
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 846, in launch_instance
>>>     app.start()
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 499, in start
>>>     self.io_loop.start()
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 132, in start
>>>     self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 541, in run_forever
>>>     self._run_once()
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1786, in _run_once
>>>     handle._run()
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
>>>     self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 122, in _handle_events
>>>     handler_func(fileobj, events)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
>>>     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 452, in _handle_events
>>>     self._handle_recv()
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 481, in _handle_recv
>>>     self._run_callback(callback, msg)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 431, in _run_callback
>>>     callback(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 300, in null_wrapper
>>>     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
>>>     return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
>>>     handler(stream, idents, msg)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
>>>     user_expressions, allow_stdin)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
>>>     res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
>>>     return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
>>>     interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2828, in run_ast_nodes
>>>     if self.run_code(code, result):
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
>>>     exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>>> 
>>>   File "<ipython-input-202-176df26aa2ef>", line 24, in <module>
>>>     validation_data=data_test)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/wandb/integration/keras/keras.py", line 167, in new_v2
>>>     return old_v2(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
>>>     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1216, in fit
>>>     tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 878, in train_function
>>>     return step_function(self, iterator)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 867, in step_function
>>>     outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in run_step
>>>     outputs = model.train_step(data)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 816, in train_step
>>>     self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 531, in minimize
>>>     loss, var_list=var_list, grad_loss=grad_loss, tape=tape)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 583, in _compute_gradients
>>>     grads_and_vars = self._get_gradients(tape, loss, var_list, grad_loss)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 464, in _get_gradients
>>>     grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list, grad_loss)
```

I would appreciate any help understanding that.

Comment: It would give a better clarity if you provide the entire code prior to this one as the shape of data_test needs to be seen. However, we need to always keep an eye on the tensor shape flow. Please check the [reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) function for your reference.